# Desktop icon in linux ubuntu qt

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, icons, desktop

Can someone give me a strait up answer on how to set up application icon in linux.
I have an application developed in Qt and I wont to show it on desktop but I wont to change it's default icon. I know that in linux I can't make icon as part of binary but how to connect icon with application?

Thanks...

Comment: you may find better answer at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

Unix binaries don’t know about the concept resources of icons. Instead, a desktop entry file is used to describe each application. These files have the file name extension of desktop and are usually stored in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/applications` or `/usr/share/applications`.

An Example of a .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=My Application
Exec=myapplication %F
MimeType=image/x-mydata;
Icon=/install/path/myicon.png
```

The line reading `[Desktop Entry]` tells you that what follows is an entry for a desktop entry. Next is Type, which tells you that the entry will describe an application. According to Name, the application is called My Application. The Exec line tells the desktop what command to issue to start the application; in this case, it is `myapplication`. The `%F` part tells the desktop where to list the file names if a user starts the application by trying to open one or more data files. The connection between these data files and the application is handled using the `MimeType` entry that defines the mime type; that is, the file type that the application handles. The last line, Icon, tells you which icon to use. The easiest way is to specify an absolute path to the icon. If you specify only the file name, you must determine where to store the icon file so that the desktop environment can find it.

When installing applications on Unix, it is common to support the make target install,
which enables the user to type make install to copy the application files to a global location.
This is supported by QMake using install sets.